# html (template) generated out of vaiable data

Tags: angular, templates

I have a basic typescript file for an angular 2 (or 4 rather) application like this:

```
// imports

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  template: `<div>HELLO</div>` // <- this template
})
export class Component implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Now my question is: is it possible to have the template above, which holds the components html be generated out of a variable?

As for more detailed information: I am getting a json object from my backend that contains a property "html" which holds an entire html file which I want to display. I will probably load this in the `ngOnInit`, now I just don't know how I can tell angular to use it for the template.

Comment: you will need to compile the component dynamically, see [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e), `Creating components on the fly` section

Comment: The answers I got below seem to work just fine, I set my htmlData in the ngOnInit and display it, just at the moment I do get a 404 when using my http.get in the service, will have to ask my backend about that. Though generally the answers I got work just fine.

Comment: with the `innerHTML` approach you **will not be able** to use any Angular specific things in HTML - binding, interpolations, child components and directive

Comment: In the case in question, that is actually fine as the backend also has to generate a PDF out of the same HTML and there of course they couldn't use any Angular specific things either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a simple component, that contains only div element.

you can simply bind the [innerHtml] property on the div element with the data
returned from backed.
in the component class i use ngOnInit life-cycle hook in order to request the template from the backend.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div [innerHtml]='myTemplate'>
    </div>
    `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  myTemplate = '';

  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => { 
      this.myTemplate = '<h1> Raed Khalaf </h1>'
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```